# Custom Magento View.phtml file called via xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

What is the code to pull in a custom view.phtml file via custom layout update (in admin > catalog > manage products > specific product) with magento?  I would really like to do this in local.xml for specific products.

I found this:

```
<PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_shirts>
<reference name="product.info">
  <action method="setTemplate"><template>my/custom/product/view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

But this code is for attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can do that in local.xml. But Custom Layout Updates were made for situation like that. Just write there your XML:

```
<reference name="product.info">
  <action method="setTemplate"><template>my/custom/product/view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Or if you need to apply the same view.phtml for several products, you can create a new theme containing just one catalog/prodcut/view.phtml and make it extend your current theme. Then apply this theme only for products you need.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking for, but I am guessing you want to use your own view.phtml file and don't know how to have the xml layout file point to that new file.

first look for the file:

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/layout/catalog.xml
```

This file essentially controls what blocks will be called within the catalog of products.  If you look for the line:

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
```

You can change the template= portion to point to your custom view.phtml file.  Just remember that the file structure starts at the template file:

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/template
```

So you will need to store your view file within that template file if you use this method.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am actually trying to keep my existing view.phtml intact and in use, but I need to create a custom one that is only called for one specific product.  I was hopping this could be one.

Comment: My advice would be to keep one view.phtml file and to have it have a simple if statement that would check to see which view page to display and then use getChildHtml('viewpageX') and define blocks customized for each page.  If this sounds like what you need I can repost an answer and give more details